# Oracle GL tree hierarchy

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, treenode, bi-publisher

This is the code:

```
SELECT
  'FXE_I_823' AS KEY,
  listagg(ftn.pk1_start_value || '|' || ffvv.description, '|')
    within GROUP (ORDER BY DEPTH) "TREE_CODE"
FROM 
fnd_tree_node ftn,
fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv
WHERE 1=1
AND ftn.pk1_start_value = ffvv.flex_value
AND ftn.tree_code = 'ARA40'
AND ffvv.value_category = 'COST CENTER'
```

I am getting the below output:

```
ARA40|ARA40|REG059|Reg 59 - Ops-Transport North|DST0418|Dist 418 Trans OpsPhiladelphia|CLU5110|Cluster 5110|SPK5110|Spoke Centers 5110|1623501|1623501 - LOMG Retail Location|1623507|1623507 - Retail Freight Service ACIM
```

But I am expecting the output like this:

```
ARA40|REG059|Reg 59 - Ops-Transport North|DST0418|Dist 418 Trans OpsPhiladelphia|CLU5110|Cluster 5110|SPK5110|Spoke Centers 5110|1623501|1623501 - LOMG Retail Location
ARA40|REG059|Reg 59 - Ops-Transport North|DST0418|Dist 418 Trans OpsPhiladelphia|CLU5110|Cluster 5110|SPK5110|Spoke Centers 5110|1623507|1623507 - Retail Freight Service ACIM
```

The last node should not come in first line and come in second line like recusrion and also the parent node ARA40 should not fetch description only child nodes from second value should have description. Can someone please help

Comment: "...The last node should not come in first line and come in second line..." -- Use the `ORDER BY` clause to specify how you want the result to be sorted.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the [fnd_tree_node](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/applications-common/22d/oedma/fndtreenode-23603.html) table should have a parent/child relationship between values. The goal appears to be:

1. begin at the first child node in the tree
2. find each leaf node under that hierarchy level
3. build the path between node level 1 and node level n - including delimiters and descriptions
4. return each result on a separate row

This can be accomplished using a [hierichical query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html) starting with each
value at the second-lowest depth and connecting by its parent values. The tree can be flattened using **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH**. The desired rows (leaves) may be filtered using the **CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF** pseudocolumn.

**Note on SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH:** If the separator character (second parameter) appears anywhere within the data for the first parameter, one will receive an **ORA-30004** error. That is why a placeholder is used in the example below.

```
SELECT     'FXE_I_823' key
          ,ftn.tree_code
           || REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ftn.pk1_start_value
                                          || CHR(0)
                                          || ffvv.description
                                          ,'|')
                     ,CHR(0)
                     ,'|') tree_code
  FROM     fnd_tree_node      ftn
          ,fnd_flex_values_vl ffvv
 WHERE     1 = 1
   AND     ftn.pk1_start_value = ffvv.flex_value
   AND     ftn.tree_code = 'ARA40'
   AND     ffvv.value_category = 'COST CENTER'
   AND     CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ftn.pk1_start_value = ftn.parent_pk1_value
START WITH depth = 1 -- root node is at depth zero
```